# Valid-Ready handshake in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am trying to learn valid/ready handshake in verilog. In particular, I am interested to use ready as a flag that indicates the successful transaction of data (i.e., `ready_in` becomes high after `valid_out` goes high). I would like to explain my problem using a very simple Verilog example. I have written a convolutional encoder (code below)

```
module Conv_Encoder_Core(
    input wire clk,                 
    input wire reset,        
    input wire in_bit,
    output reg out_A,
    output reg out_B,
    input wire sleep,          
    input wire valid_in,
    input wire ready_in,
    output reg valid_out,
    output reg ready_out);

reg [5:0] S;
wire S_A, S_B, clkON;
assign S_A = S[1] ^ S[2] ^ S[4] ^S[5];
assign S_B = S[0] ^ S[1] ^ S[2] ^S[5];
assign clkON = clk & !sleep;

always @(posedge clkON)begin
    if (reset) begin
        S <=0;
        valid_out <=0; 
        ready_out <=0;
    end else if (valid_in) begin
        out_A <= in_bit ^ S_A;
        out_B <= in_bit ^ S_B;
        valid_out <=1;
        if (ready_in)begin
            S<= S<<1;
            S[0] <=in_bit;
            ready_out <=1;
        end else begin
            ready_out <=0;
        end

    end else begin
        valid_out <=0;
        ready_out <=0;
    end


end 
endmodule
```

I am interested to use `ready_in` flag as an indicator that data `out_A` and `out_B` are received by the next block, so my block can accept the new data by setting `ready_out` flag high. I have written a testbench for this block, however, I am not getting the results I am expecting

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ns
module TB_Conv();
reg  clk;
//---------------clock generator-----------------------
initial begin
    clk = 1'b0; 
    #5; 
    clk = 1'b1; 
    forever    begin
        #5 clk = ~clk;      
    end
end
//------------------ dump -----------------------
initial begin
    $dumpfile("dumpVCD.vcd");
    $dumpvars(10);  
end

localparam N_DATA=10;
reg in_bits_vec [0:N_DATA-1];
initial begin
    in_bits_vec[0] = 1'b1;
    in_bits_vec[1] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[2] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[3] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[4] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[5] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[6] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[7] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[8] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[9] = 1'b1;
end
reg in_bit, ready_in,reset, valid_in;
Conv_Encoder_Core UUT(.clk(clk),
                        .reset(reset),
                        .in_bit(in_bit),
                        .out_A(out_A),
                        .out_B(out_B),
                        .sleep(1'b0),
                        .valid_in(valid_in),
                        .ready_in(ready_in),
                        .valid_out(valid_out),
                        .ready_out(ready_out));

//---------------- code starts here -------------------//
reg [3:0] addr;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset)begin
        addr<=0;
        valid_in <=0;
        in_bit <=0;
    end else if (addr < 10) begin
        in_bit <= in_bits_vec[addr];
        valid_in <=1'b1;
        if (ready_out) begin
            addr <= addr+1'b1;
        end

    end else  begin
        in_bit <=0;
        valid_in <=0;
    end

    if (valid_out==1) ready_in <= 1;
    else              ready_in <= 0;

end 
// ----------- reset logic -----------//
reg [3:0] cnt;
initial cnt=0;
always @(negedge clk)begin
    if (cnt<5) begin
        reset = 1;
        cnt=cnt+1;
    end else  reset =0;
end

initial begin
 #1000;
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

if you look at the input data (in the testbech), you can see it is `1000000000`. I am expecting to see `1` being passed through `S` register as follows:

```
S = 000000 //at beginning
S = 000001 // after ready_out=1
S = 000010
S = 000100
```

however, the results I get is entirely different(please see snapshot).
Another problem I have is that `inbit=1` continues two clock cycles more than what I expect. in fact when `ready_out=1`, I expect to see that `in_bit` becomes zero but this happens two clock cycles later(yellow cursor in the snapshot ).

I would be most grateful if someone could explain what I do wrong in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Conv_Encoder_Core

```
module Conv_Encoder_Core
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,
    input wire in_bit,
    output reg out_A,
    output reg out_B,
    input wire sleep,
    // input channel
    input  wire inp_valid_i,
    output wire inp_ready_o,
    // output channel
    output reg out_valid_o,
    input  reg out_ready_i
);

reg [5:0] S;
wire S_A, S_B, clkON;
assign S_A = S[1] ^ S[2] ^ S[4] ^S[5];
assign S_B = S[0] ^ S[1] ^ S[2] ^S[5];
assign clkON = clk & !sleep;


// -- Changes start here -- //
wire wr_en;
reg full_r;

assign wr_en = ~full_r | out_ready_i;
always @(posedge clkON)begin
    if (reset) begin
        S <=0;
        full_r <=0;
    end else begin
        if (wr_en) begin
            if (inp_valid_i) begin
                full_r  <= 1;
                out_A   <= in_bit ^ S_A;
                out_B   <= in_bit ^ S_B;
                S       <= S<<1;
                S[0]    <=in_bit;
            end else begin
                full_r  <= 0;
            end
        end
    end
end

assign inp_ready_o = wr_en;
assign out_valid_o = full_r;

endmodule
```

### tb

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ns
module tb();
reg  clk;
//---------------clock generator-----------------------
initial begin
    clk = 1'b0; 
    #5; 
    clk = 1'b1; 
    forever    begin
        #5 clk = ~clk;      
    end
end
//------------------ dump -----------------------
initial begin
    $dumpfile("dumpVCD.vcd");
    $dumpvars(10);  
end

localparam N_DATA=10;
reg in_bits_vec [0:N_DATA-1];
initial begin
    in_bits_vec[0] = 1'b1;
    in_bits_vec[1] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[2] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[3] = 1'b0; 
    in_bits_vec[4] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[5] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[6] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[7] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[8] = 1'b0;
    in_bits_vec[9] = 1'b1;
end
reg in_bit, reset, inp_valid, inp_ready, out_valid, out_ready;
Conv_Encoder_Core UUT(.clk(clk),
                        .reset(reset),
                        .in_bit(in_bit),
                        .out_A(out_A),
                        .out_B(out_B),
                        .sleep(1'b0),
                        // input channel
                        .inp_valid_i(inp_valid),
                        .inp_ready_o(inp_ready),
                        // output channel
                        .out_valid_o(out_valid),
                        .out_ready_i(out_ready));

//---------------- code starts here -------------------//
reg [3:0] addr;

// -- Transmitter Side -- //
always @(posedge clk) begin: ff_addr
    if (reset)begin
        addr <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (addr < 10) begin
            if (inp_valid && inp_ready) begin
                addr <= addr + 1;
            end
        end else begin
            addr <= 0;
        end
    end
end

assign inp_valid = (addr < 10) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

assign in_bit = in_bits_vec[addr];

// -- Receiver Side -- //
always @(posedge clk) begin: ff_ready_in
    if (reset) begin
        out_ready <= 0;
    end else begin
        out_ready <= $urandom_range(0, 1); // some randomness on the receiver, otherwise, we won't see if our DUT behaves correctly in case of ready=0
    end
end

// ----------- reset logic -----------//
reg [3:0] cnt;
initial cnt=0;
always @(negedge clk)begin
    if (cnt<5) begin
        reset = 1;
        cnt=cnt+1;
    end else  reset =0;
end

initial begin
 #1000;
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

---

### Issues with your implementation

**Bad protocol definition & implementation**

You are defining a protocol that looks more like "request/acknowledge" than "ready/valid" one, because data transmissions in your protocol are acknowledged after a **one-cycle delay**. What you need is concurrent transmission acknowledge in the **same cycle**, something like the following:

[image]

A valid data transmission is indicated by the Transmitter through `valid=1` and are acknowledged by the Receiver through `ready=1`. So, a data transmission is valid only when `valid && ready` in the same cycle. Note that input `data` is equivalent to `in_bit` in your case, while output `data` is `out_A` and `out_B`.

**Input/Output ready/valid channel confusion**

If you add a processing/buffering unit between the Transmitter and the Receiver of the above channel, then what you got is something like this:

[image]

In that case, your buffer is the `Conv_Encoder_Core` module and, apart from its internal core logic, it must expose an **input** ready/valid channel, from which it receives input data, and an **output** one, from which it outputs its data. Also note that the Transmitter and the Receiver, are implemented by the testbench code (`tb` module). See 
"Transmitter Side" and "Receiver Side" comments in code.